# Why I have to type "./" always before an executable to execute it in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell

When I compile e.g. x.c by:

```
GCC x.c -o x
```

To execute result I have to write:

```
./x
```

And just typing:

```
x
```

Fails with this message:

> x: command not found

This means Linux does not search current directory for it! Is there (I'm sure there is) any reasonable issue behind this behaviour?

Comment: Because it's the rules.

Comment: @DanH: Then explain "the rules" please.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because by default, the current working directory is not in the `PATH` variable.

This is a security/convenience measure.  If you have binaries/scripts called e.g. `cd`, `ls`, etc. in your current working directory, it would be very annoying if they were run by default.

Comment: Thank you so much Oli. Now, I know why I should type two extra characters;) good design!

Comment: The answer is only partly correct. The problem could be surrounded if the current directory was only used as last option. Then standard tools would still be found first.

Comment: Also, shell builtins take precendence (i.e. when you type `cd` in `bash`, it executes a routine internal to bash and not `/bin/cd`) unless you prepend with `.\`

Comment: One of the original *nix security measures, it forces system or admin compiled binaries that are in the system assigned path command to be executed. Nothing so bad as someone to log in as root on a help desk question, go to a user directory, type **ls** and find they loaded a bomb left by a user.

Comment: @userunknown: And the first time you typoed `sl`, you've got the same problem. Only trusted directories should be in `$PATH` and relative paths like `.` are _never_ a trusted directory for an interactive shell.

Comment: @ultrasawblade: Bad example; `cd` is one of the few shell builtins that cannot be replaced by an external program.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig I take your point about typos but if you're building in typo protection to executing commands, why not do the same for `rm -f` vs `rm -r`? This seems like one of those things that makes people who like it feel safer, whereas those who don't just see it as an annoyance.

Comment: @Basic: If I type `rm -r target` when I meant `rm -f target` there is usually no difference. If I type `rm -f target` when I meant `rm -r target`, either there's no difference or removal outright fails. Furthermore, I think _every time_ before I type `rm`, _especially_ if I'm adding `-f` or `-r` or a glob - it's a dangerous command by its nature. No one thinks before `ls`ing.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the current directory is not in the $PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by adding the current directory (represented by a single dot)  to the `PATH` environment variable.
The way to do it depends on the shell you are using.
if you are using bash, you can add the line   `export PATH=$PATH:.` to the `.bashrc` file in your home directory.
if you are using csh or tcsh add the line 
`set PATH = ($PATH .)` to the file .cshrc in your home directory.
IMHO, for a home desktop computer this is an acceptable thing to do - security wise.

Comment: I did not know we can add . to PATH, however, doing this will decrease security, right?